# How to concatenate columns

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation, multiple-columns

So I have following table in Excel

```
 A    B    C    D    E    F    G
 4    5    5    4    8    8    9
 4    8    7    7    8    7    8
 2    1    7    4    7    8    8
 upto 2000th row
```

I need it to be formatted as following but using VBA only

```
 A    B           C
 4    55488       9
 4    87787       8
 2    17478       8
 upto 2000th row
```

Any suggestions on how can I do this ?

Comment: Do it manually and record a macro.

Comment: Iterate through all rows (`For`) and use something like this `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i, 2) & Cells(i, 3) & Cells(i, 4) ...`.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please include your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Santosh()
   For i = 1 To 2400
      Cells(i, "B") = Cells(i, "B") & Cells(i, "C") & Cells(i, "D") & Cells(i, "E") & Cells(i, "F")
   Next i
   Columns("C:F").Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: It's good to see you can delete user data without being asked and get chosen as better answer XD

Comment: lol I am done here. I am only indignant because I know and everyone who understands programming knows that I have the better code (matches user's stated requirements).

Comment: @findwindow  I agree that your code is better *(that why I upvoted it)*.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say anything about columns past C so I kept them as is...

```
sub SO()

Dim c As String

For i = 2 To 2000
c = Cells(i, 2) & Cells(i, 3) & Cells(i, 4) & Cells(i, 5) & Cells(i, 6)
Cells(i, 2) = c
Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 7)
Next

end sub
```

Comment: This works fine thanks but I want to delete the columns beyond C how can I do it ?

Comment: Add `columns("D:G").delete` at the end.

Comment: @Santosh lol really? You don't ask for requirement and when I provide answer upon request, you remove check mark lololol

Comment: Ok... kinda amazing one can mistakenly uncheck an answer then recheck another but sure thanks.

Comment: Actually Gary's and your answer are right wanted to mark both of the right but I think I can't

Comment: Sigh. You don't even realize Gary did something you did not ask him to do. (Imagine if you wanted to keep data. Ouch!) I wrote mine entirely to your specifications, nothing more, nothing less. I did assume row started on 2 because it's far less painful in the event you have headers.

Comment: I agree that your code is better.

Answer (score 0):

You could have recorded a macro yourself to do something like this:

```
Sub Test()

    ' add new column
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    ' add formula in the newly created column B
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]&RC[2]&RC[3]&RC[4]&RC[5]"

    ' repeat the fomula for 2000 rows
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B2000")

    ' copy and paste over itself as values so that the formula is converted to resulting data
    Range("B1:B2000").Select
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

    ' remove C through G columns
    Range("C6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("C:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

This code was directly generated from recording a macro and modified to suit 2000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the results of doing it manually and recording a macro...
far more involved than coding it by hand, but far easier to do imo.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Application.Left = 406.75
    Application.Top = 289
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-5],RC[-4],RC[-3],RC[-2],RC[-1])"
    Range("G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("G1:G2000").Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("B:F").Select
    Range("F1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("D2").Select
    Application.Left = 17.5
    Application.Top = 277.75
    Application.Goto Reference:="Macro1"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column and concatenate the columns together and then delete the other columns.

```
 A    B    C    D    E    F    G
 4    5    5    4    8    8    9
 4    8    7    7    8    7    8
 2    1    7    4    7    8    8

 A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
 4    5    5    4    8    8    *    9
 4    8    7    7    8    7    *    8
 2    1    7    4    7    8    *    8

where * = cstr(B2) & cstr(C2) & cstr(D2) & cstr(E2) & cstr(F2)
```